# Making feed slider to use random posts instead of first ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, slider, feed

I made a slider using the code I found somewhere over the net to display posts from two labels from blogger feed API. So there is a problem that this code is a little bit confusing to me and I am asking how to anapt this code to pick for example random 7 posts.

```
<style type="text/css">
ul.featured-widget-list,ul.featured-widget-list li{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;position:relative }ul.featured-widget-list li{display:none}ul.featured-widget-list li:nth-child(1){display:block;line-height:0}ul.featured-widget-list img{border:0;width:100%;height:auto}ul.featured-widget-list .featuredbg{width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;z-index:2;left:0;top:0;opacity:.6;background-image:url(https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-1_Vnfz23h0E/V0m7kzHpgiI/AAAAAAAALlU/f763ScY-PBc2UnqNX3Tf20lyvHxtRo9qwCLcB/s400/overlay-bg.png);background-position:0% 100%;background-repeat:repeat-x}ul.featured-widget-list .featuredbg:hover{opacity:.1}ul.featured-widget-list h5{position:absolute;left:0;right:0;text-align:center;bottom:10px;z-index:2;color:#fff;margin:0;text-transform: capitalize;padding:10px 20px;line-height:1.9em;letter-spacing:0.3px;font: 600 16px, sans-serif;overflow:hidden}ul.featured-widget-list li:hover h5{bottom:30px}ul.featured-widget-list .featured-meta{font: 11px , sans-serif;letter-spacing:0.3px;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;text-align:center;z-index:2;color:#fff;opacity:0}ul.featured-widget-list h5, ul.featured-widget-list .featured-meta {display:none!important;visibility:hidden!imporant;opacity:0!important;height: 0!important;}ul.featured-widget-list li:hover .featured-meta{bottom:20px;opacity:1}.feat-buttons{position:absolute;top:50%;left:0;z-index:5;width:100%}
.feat-buttons a{text-indent:-9999px;margin:0 7px;width:15px;height:15px;padding:5px;background:#000;-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";filter: alpha(opacity=60);-moz-opacity:0.6;-khtml-opacity:0.6;opacity:0.6;position:relative;-webkit-border-radius: 50%;-moz-border-radius: 50%;border-radius: 50%;}.feat-prev{float:left;}.feat-next{float:right;}.feat-buttons a.feat-prev::before, .feat-buttons a.feat-next::before{content:"";width:0;height:0;border-width:6px 7px;border-style:solid;border-color:transparent #fff transparent transparent;position:absolute;top:50%;margin-top:-6px;margin-left:-11px;left:50%}
.feat-buttons a.feat-next::before{border-color:transparent transparent transparent #fff;margin-left:-3px}
#slidecontainter {max-width: 270px;max-height: 270px;position:relative;margin: 0 auto;display: inline-block;}
#centerwrapckass{text-align:center;}
#spacebetweentwo{width:90px;display: inline-block;}
@media only screen and (max-width:448px){#spacebetweentwo{display:none!important;}}
</style>
<div id="centerwrapckass">
<div  id="slidecontainter" ><div id="featuredbwidget"></div></div>
<div  id="spacebetweentwo" ></div>
<div  id="slidecontainter" ><div id="featuredbwidget1"></div></div>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
featuredbwidget({
listURL:"",
featuredNum:7,
listbyLabel:"Познати%20велики%20песници",
feathumbSize:150,
interval:1000,
autoplay:false,
featuredID:"#featuredbwidget"
});
featuredbwidget({
listURL:"",/*ostaviti  prazno*/
featuredNum:7,
listbyLabel:"Данашњи%20песници",
feathumbSize:150,
interval:1000,
autoplay:false,
featuredID:"#featuredbwidget1"
});
function featuredbwidget(a) {
    (function(e) {
        var h = {
            listURL: "",
            featuredNum: 3,
            featuredID: "",
            feathumbSize: 300,
            interval: 5000,
            autoplay: false,
            loadingFeatured: "nextfeatured",
            pBlank: "https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-EOu4Rrgcryo/V0m8dV7MU1I/AAAAAAAALlg/4h5vQaHpQiMdkvtUdDbu0LtjJRvgPERYwCLcB/s500/no-image.png",
            byMonth: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
            listbyLabel: false
        };
        h = e.extend({}, h, a);
        var g = e(h.featuredID);
        var d = h.featuredNum * 200;
        g.html('<div class="featslider"><ul class="featured-widget-list"></ul><div class="feat-buttons"><a href="#" class="feat-prev">Prev</a><a href="#" class="feat-next">Next</a></div></div>');
        var f = function(w) {
            var q, k, m, u, x, p, t, v, r, l = "",
                s = w.feed.entry;
            for (var o = 0; o < s.length; o++) {
                for (var n = 0; n < s[o].link.length; n++) {
                    if (s[o].link[n].rel == "alternate") {
                        q = s[o].link[n].href;
                        break
                    }
                }
                if ("media$thumbnail" in s[o]) {
                    u = s[o].media$thumbnail.url.replace(/\/s[0-9]+\-c/g, "/s" + h.feathumbSize + "-c")
                } else {
                    u = h.pBlank.replace(/\/s[0-9]+(\-c|\/)/, "/s" + h.feathumbSize + "$1")
                }
                k = s[o].title.$t;
                r = s[o].published.$t.substring(0, 10);
                m = s[o].author[0].name.$t;
                x = r.substring(0, 4);
                p = r.substring(5, 7);
                t = r.substring(8, 10);
                v = h.byMonth[parseInt(p, 10) - 1];
                l += '<li><a href="' + q + '"><div class="featuredbg"></div><img class="featuredthumb" src="' + u + '"/><h5>' + k + '</h5></a><div class="featured-meta"><span class="fdate"><span class="fday">' + t + '</span> <span class="fmonth">' + v + '</span> <span class="fyear">' + x + '</span></span> - <span class="fauthor">' + m + "</span></div></li>"
            }
            e("ul", g).append(l).addClass(h.loadingFeatured)
        };
        var c = function() {
            e(h.featuredID + " .feat-next").click()
        };
        var b = function() {
            e.get((h.listURL === "" ? window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host : h.listURL) + "/feeds/posts/summary" + (h.listbyLabel === false ? "" : "/-/" + h.listbyLabel) + "?max-results=" + h.featuredNum + "&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script", f, "jsonp");
            setTimeout(function() {
                e(h.featuredID + " .feat-prev").click(function() {
                    e(h.featuredID + " .featslider li:first").before(e(h.featuredID + " .featslider li:last"));
                    return false
                });
                e(h.featuredID + " .feat-next").click(function() {
                    e(h.featuredID + " .featslider li:last").after(e(h.featuredID + " .featslider li:first"));
                    return false
                });
                if (h.autoplay) {
                    var i = h.interval;
                    var j = setInterval(c, i);
                    e(h.featuredID + " .featslider li:first").before(e(h.featuredID + " .featslider li:last"));
                    e(h.featuredID + " .featslider").hover(function() {
                        clearInterval(j)
                    }, function() {
                        j = setInterval(c, i)
                    })
                }
                e("ul", g).removeClass(h.loadingFeatured)
            }, d)
        };
        e(document).ready(b)
    })(jQuery)
};
//]]>
</script>
```

Does anybody have any idea how to accomplish this? Probably need to use function Math.random(), and to make some for loop to be sure that random values do not get duplicated.

Comment: can you precise us which API/version this uses? If the API does support random posts retreiving, it should be easy. If not, you'll probably have to retreive all posts and randomize yourself (or rather retreive only the IDs, randomize, then retreive their contents)

Comment: blogger feed api json http://www.danpros.com/2013/08/blogger-json-feed-api http://www.mybloggertricks.com/2015/10/introduction-to-blogger-json-feeds-and-blogger-data-api.html it doesnt support server side randomizing

Comment: ok so this is the V3 of the API.. can't help you right now as it is big hurry here. But i can tell that you would need to use for example 2 consecutive `e.get( /* ... */ )`, first for all IDs, then to get their content. You'll need to properly use callbacks for that (for example, i think the `setTimeout()` here is a bit dangerous and might break if connexion is slow, should be in the callbak `f` imo)